# Statsmodels OLS and MSE

Tags: least-squares, python, mse

So, I have data set and I calculate the model parameters and errors using statsmodels:

```
result = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
result.summary()
```

Now, `result.mse_resid`, `result.mse_total` provide MSE of the residuals and total mean squared error.

Reading the statistics tutorials I see that $MSE=\frac{RSS}{DFE}$, where DFE is degrees of freedom for error. I should be able to calculate MSE as follows:

```
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X,y)
yp=reg.predict(X)
resid=y-yp
rss=np.sum(resid**2)
MSE=rss/(result.nobs-2)
```

What is the MSE calculated using OLS and why is it different from this one (or what am I not understanding correctly)?

Comment: Why do you think they're different?

Comment: Not enough information has been given to resolve this question.

Answer (score 2):

My guess without thinking too hard about this. Statsmodels doesn't include a constant by default. Scikit-learn does. So you need to do `X = sm.add_constant(X)` and include the constant by hand, if you don't use the formula interface to statsmodels.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry! I completely forgot to say that I did that. I am using the Tobaco and Alcohol data set for UK, so my whole MSE expression included: `X = df[["Tobacco"]].values
X = sm.add_constant(X)  # add the intercept term
reg = LinearRegression()`